# Remove specific XML element in Delphi

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-7

I have an xml document looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Person xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ExtensionData />
  <Name>ali</Name>
  <Age>37</Age>
  <Father>
    <ExtensionData />
    <Name>I</Name>
    <Age>72</Age>
  </Father>
  <Mother>
    <ExtensionData />
    <Name>M</Name>
    <Age>62</Age>
  </Mother>
</Person>
```

I am using Delphi 7.

How can I remove all **ExtensionData** elements in XML document like this?

Comment: Why XML library are you using?

Comment: He's probably using the default TXMLDocument wrapper.

Comment: Yes, I'm using TXMLDocument.

Comment: `ExtensionData` is an element, not an attribute, and in this example it has no attributes of its own, either.  It is important to get the terminology correct because elements and attributes are accessed in different ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `IXMLNodeList.Delete()` or `IXMLNodeList.Remove()` method to remove nodes:

```pascal
var
  Root: IXMLNode;
begin
  Root := XMLDocument1.DocumentElement;
  Root.ChildNodes.Delete('ElementData');
  for I := 0 to Root.ChildNodes.Count-1 do
    Root.ChildNodes[I].ChildNodes.Delete('ElementData');
end;
```

```pascal
var
  Root, Child, Node: IXMLNode;
begin
  Root := XMLDocument1.DocumentElement;
  Node := Root.ChildNodes.FindNode('ElementData');
  if Node <> nil then Root.ChildNodes.Remove(Node);
  for I := 0 to Root.ChildNodes.Count-1 do
  begin
    Child := Root.ChildNodes[I];
    Node := Child.ChildNodes.FindNode('ElementData');
    if Node <> nil then Child.ChildNodes.Remove(Node);
  end;
end;
```

If you want to remove all `ElementData` elements regardless of their depth within the document, a recursive procedure can do that:

```pascal
procedure RemoveElementData(Node: IXMLNode);
var
  Root, Child: IXMLNode;
begin
  repeat until Node.ChildNodes.Delete('ElementData') = -1;
  for I := 0 to Node.ChildNodes.Count-1 do
    RemoveElementData(Node.ChildNodes[I]);
  end;
end;

begin
  RemoveElementData(XMLDocument1.DocumentElement);
end;
```

Comment: After removing a node, I'm saving the document using `IXMLDocument`'s `SaveToFile` procedure but it writes an empty line for each removed node. Any idea about how to avoid this? (I'm testing on Delphi 2007)

Comment: @ExDev that happens when the original document has whitespace text nodes (line breaks, etc) between element nodes, such as if you enable the `poPreserveWhiteSpace` flag in the `ParseOptions` property when loading the document, and then you do not removing those extra text nodes when removing element nodes.

Comment: I'm creating a new document from scratch. For readability reasons, I've added `doNodeAutoIndent` to the document's `Options`. Then I'm removing a node using the `Remove` function, after doing this, what should I do in order to remove the empty line? [example](https://s2.postimg.org/pjt5l6jix/remove_node.png)

Comment: @ExDev indentation is done using text nodes. Like I said, just remove the extra text nodes that preceed/follow the element node you are removing. They are children of the same parent node.

Comment: You're right, I've removed the extra text nodes and the empty line is disappeared. I would never have thought that indentation was done by adding "fake" nodes. Thanks